# Perl pocket reference (online)

Tags: perl

Looking for a Perl cheatsheet, or online version of a pocket reference.

[Perl 5 Cheat Sheet](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlcheat.html) is a little on the short end of what I'm looking for, and the [Perl Pocket Reference, Fourth Edition](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596003746/) is available to buy as a PDF, but if there's a free version of something equal or better -- I'd much rather use it; in part because I'd like to reference it.

Questions, feedback, comments -- just comment, thanks!!

Comment: I prefer the published paper copy of the Pocket Reference: easy to add notes (shift-unshift-push-pop is a favorite diagram I made), add index items, carry & read it anywhere there is light.  An online file is easy to search for specific text, if you have the file and a PC with you (or a phone w/ a web browser that renders all the fonts correctly).  perldoc is the online tool I use more often than other online aids: if you are at the computer, use the doc w/ the most detailed data.

Comment: It's a shame they didn't update the Perl Pocket Reference to Perl 5.12 (or even 5.14 which should be out later this year) when they did the ebook version. Still, the 5.8 reference is still very actual. It just misses some awesome new stuff like `given`/`when`, smart-match operator `~~` and some regular expression modifiers that are new.

Comment: @Htbaa: Please post your comment on the Perl Pocket Reference that covers 5.8, with comments on stuff that's missing in 5.12, or deprecated -- and I'll take it as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a shame they didn't update the **Perl Pocket Reference** to Perl 5.12 (or even 5.14 which should be out later this year) when they did the ebook version. Still, the 5.8 reference is still very actual. It just misses some awesome new stuff like `given`/`when`, smart-match operator `~~` and some regular expression modifiers that are new.

For all that has changed between the different versions of Perl I must refer you to the perldelta documents. To see what has changed between 5.8 and 5.10 see [perl5100delta](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.12.3/pod/perl5100delta.pod) and [perl5101delta](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.12.3/pod/perl5101delta.pod) for the differences between 5.10.0 and 5.10.1. For Perl 5.12 see [perl51200delta](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.12.3/pod/perl5120delta.pod) and the subsequent *perl51xxdelta* documents.

I can't remember the current Perl Pocket Reference to mention deprecated features though, but it probably did. Don't have it in hand reach right now.

Answer (score 4):

Probably this is a good choice for you

http://www.squirrel.nl/pub/perlref-5.004.1.pdf

I am assuming what you want is just a quick reference for syntax, list of operators, check if there is an inbuilt function exists or not etc

Comment: That book is really outdated and is for Perl 5.004, almost 14 years old! Latest stable Perl is at version 5.12.3.

Answer (score 1):

A quick google has turned up:

1. http://johnbokma.com/perl/perl-quick-reference-card.html
2. http://www.catonmat.net/blog/perl-pack-unpack-printf-cheat-sheet/
3. http://www.catonmat.net/blog/perls-special-variable-cheat-sheet/

Also look through some of the other perldoc material, for example [`perldoc perlreref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref.html), or search the perlfaq with `perldoc -q <query>`. While a cheat sheet is nice, there is very little that cannot be found in `perldoc`.

Comment: +1 Thanks for posting! So, main issue is none of the reference you link to state the version of Perl they apply to. I've googled the topic as well, and that's the number one issue I've run across. Thanks for the pointers on using perldoc.